# Fix div when position reaches 85px from top of window on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to fix 'middle_block2' to either the bottom of the fixed position 'top_block' or 85px (the height of 'top_block') from the top of the window when 'middle_block2' reaches the bottom of 'top_block' when scrolling down. Here is the code and a link to the jsfiddle.

I have it working when it reaches that top of the window but that is as far as I have been able to get.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jpolsonb/u9adhkc7/1/

HTML

```
<div class='top_block'>
<p>Top Block</p>
</div>

<div class='middle_block1'>
<p>Middle Block 1</p>
</div>

<div class ='ghost_div'>
<div class='middle_block2'>
<p>Middle Block 2</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class='bottom_block'>
<p>Bottom Block</p>
<p>Bottom Block</p>
<p>Bottom Block</p>
<p>Bottom Block</p>
<p>Bottom Block</p>
<p>Bottom Block</p>
<p>Bottom Block</p>
<p>Bottom Block</p>
<p>Bottom Block</p>
<p>Bottom Block</p>
<p>Bottom Block</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.top_block {
width:100%;
background-color: black;
height: 85px;
color:white;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
position:fixed;
}


.middle_block1 {
width:100%;
background-color: yellow;
height: 450px;
color:black;
padding-top: 85px;
z-index:2;
}

.ghost_div {
height: 85px;
background-color: red;
}

.middle_block2 {
width:100%;
background-color: blue;
height: 85px;
color:white;
}

.bottom_block {
width:100%;
background-color: red;
height: 950px;
color:white;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(function(){
    // Check the initial Position of the fixed_nav_container
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('.middle_block2').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
                    $('.middle_block2').css({position: 'fixed', top: '85px'});  
            } else {
                    $('.middle_block2').css({position: 'relative', top: '0px'});
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: you can put top as 85px at else condition how ever it is not entering to if condition >> $('.middle_block2').css({position: 'relative', top: '85px'});

Comment: Thanks but I already tried that, it just moves middle_block2 85px down into bottom_block?

Comment: yes and it will change position to relative

Comment: That's not the problem though, it needs stay where it is until the top of middle block reaches the bottom of top block, it then becomes fixed. It can't overlap the bottom block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please modify the code like this and check

```
$(function(){
    // Check the initial Position of the fixed_nav_container
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('.middle_block2').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $(document).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop-85 ) {
            $('.middle_block2').css({position: 'fixed', top: '85px'});  
        } else {
            $('.middle_block2').css({position: 'relative', top: '0px'});
        }
    });
});
```

Updated Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/u9adhkc7/4/

Comment: Thanks mate, I thought it was like that but couldn't get the syntax right. Cheers.

Comment: You could use `position: 'initial'` for the alternate state - in cases where you use the same class for container for your mobile state, which would force the hamburger to move away from its absolute positioning when alternated to relative.

Answer (score 1):

Try below mentioned code:

```
$(function(){
var topBlockheight=$('.top_block').height();
        // Check the initial Position of the fixed_nav_container
        var stickyHeaderTop = $('.middle_block2').offset().top; 
        $(window).scroll(function(){
                if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop-topBlockheight ) {
                        $('.middle_block2').css({position: 'fixed', top: '85px'});  
                } else {
                        $('.middle_block2').css({position: 'relative', top: '0px'});
                }
        });
  });
```

Updated Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/u9adhkc7/6/

Comment: Sorry someone else beat you to it. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.middle_block2 {
    width:100%;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 85px;
    color:white;
    postion: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is a jquery problem, check out the fiddle. I already have the effect working but it triggers when middle_block2 reaches the top of the window. I need it to trigger 85px from the top.